# How to use android.webkit.PluginStub

Tags: android, android-webview, mobile-webkit

I create a Android App with WebView ( embed, as main UI | HTML5 app). 
Also, I have some code to render 3d stuffs, in order to embed my 3d render, I think i need to create a plugin for showing up in WebKit.

I find "[android.webkit.PluginStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PluginStub.html)" , I search google and stackoverflow, didn't find any useful example.

Any one has any experience on PluginStub, can you share ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the Android sources at `development/samples/BrowserPlugin`, I haven't tried it as Android developers [Dianne Hackborn](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/ui1Sj4msQtg/T_nnusYi-KgJ) and [Roman Nurik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178804/172670) had said there is no actual support for them, anyways give it a try, who knows :)